# Tangent ODE solutions for $x' = f(x/t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is a continous $f(u)$ and $\varphi(t)=at$ which is a solution of $x' = f(\frac{x}{t})$. Prove that:

1. if $f'(a) < 1$ then no other solution is tangent to $\varphi(t)$ at $(0,0)$
2. if $f'(a) > 1$ then there exists infinitely many tangent solutions to $\varphi(t)$ at $(0,0)$

I am totally lost and appreciate any hints how can I tackle this.

Comment: The proposed problem is one of those *non-uniqueness* cases, where the [Picard-Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) assumptions are not satisfied. By injecting $\varphi$ in the differential equation, we get the fixed-point $a = f(a)$, and $f$ must be differentiable in the vicinity of $a$ to compute $f'(a)$... Take a look at the proof of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem to see what happens

Comment: Should I try working with Picard iteration?

Comment: It may be worth trying